# Imputing into an array with conditions

Tags: c, arrays

I want to enter user input numbers into an array (up to 5).

Once the amount of numbers in the array reaches 5 or the number "0" is entered the array is printed out with the number of numbers entered.

How would I fix this code to achieve that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    //Declare Variables
    int i,n,arr[5];

    //Insert Into Array
    printf("Input up to 5 integers:\n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d : ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] == 0) 
        {
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    //Display Array
    printf("The %d integers stored in the array are:\n", n);
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The code does not work?

Comment: What and also where is the use of `n`?

Comment: OT: Standard C requires `main()` to return `int`.

Comment: "*`//Insert Info Array`*" is the wrong wording. As it stands the array `arr` **always** has 5 elements, it's just that initially their values are not set.

Comment: Are you using Turbo-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I fix this code to achieve that?

Set `n = i` as 1st statement inside the 1st loop:

```
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    n = i;
```

And have the 2nd loop run until `n` only:

```
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
int i,n,arr[5];
```

you haven't used `n` anywhere in the code, instead you have used magic number `5`. Try this

```
int i,arr[5] = {0} /* initialize array */, n;
/* find the number of element can be stored in an array */
n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

And then rotate loop `n` times instead of magic number. For e.g

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("%d : ",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
        break;
    }
#if 0
    else { 
        continue; /* this is useless, anyhow its going to continue if if block didn't execute */
    }
#endif
}
```

And while printing the array elements, rotate loop `n` times.

```
printf("The %d integers stored in the array are:\n", i); /* use i here */
for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
{
    printf("%d\n", arr[j]);
}
```

Also the way you have declared `main()` is wrong.

```
void  main() /* Not correct. use int main(void) { } */
{
//
}
```

> From the **5.1.2.2.1  Program  startup**
>
> The function called at
>   program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype  for  this  function.   It  shall  be  defined  with  a 
>   return  type  of **int** and  with  **no parameters**:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /*...*/ }
> ```

Comment: I think this is not what OP wanted.

Comment: If the user enters `0` the 2nd loop might invoke undefined behaviour be printing out uninitialised elements of `arr`. Not nice.

Comment: @alk that case will be taken care by `int arr[5] = {} /* initialize array */` I guess ?

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed. There is an  initialiser. Was is there 10 min ago? ;) Anyway, current C requires `{0}`  at least.

Comment: And BTW, as opposed to what you write in your answer your 2nd loop still uses `5` instead of `n`.

Comment: I think you're still missing the real problem, which is that if the user enters three nonzero numbers and then enters a "0", the program should print `The 3 integers stored in the array are:` and then print *three* numbers, not five.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is basically correct.  (We'll look at a few ways to improve it in a minute.)  But since you said you wanted to read up to 5 elements **or** until the user entered a 0, this implies that we need to keep track of how many numbers actually *are* in the array, if not 5.  This is a frequent pattern: an array has some maximum capacity, but we expect that it will usually contain less than that, so we use a separate variable to keep track of the actual size.

It looks like you intended the variable `n` to serve this purpose.  You have the line

```
printf("The %d integers stored in the array are:\n", n);
```

But you don't actually set `n`, and you don't actually use it when you print the array out, either.  So there are two things to fix:

1. Add the line `n = i;` after the input loop.  After the loop, if the user didn't type a "0", if you read all 5 numbers and existed the loop because of the `i < 5` condition, `i` will be 5.  And if the user did type a "0", prematurely terminating the loop, `i` will be the array index where the user entered "0", which is one more than the last index where the user actually entered a number.  In either case, `i` will be the number of numbers filled into the array, so it's the right value to set `n` to.
2. At the end, where you print the array out, I think you want to print only the entered numbers.  So you want that last loop to run `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`.

Now, a few more things.

You've told the user to enter a "0" when they're done entering numbers, but what if there's an end-of-file condition, perhaps because they typed control-D or control-Z or whatever?  And what if they enter something that's not a number?  You should worry about these possibilities, too.  You should always check the return value from `scanf` to see if it read as many items as you expected.  You can do it like this:

```
if(scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1)
    break;
```

Now, if the user enters something non-numeric (causing `scanf` to return 0), or if there's an end-of file (causing `scanf` to return `EOF`), the loop will also terminate.  (And in fact, once you've made this change, you can tell the user to terminate the array that way, instead of checking for 0, and then it will be possible to enter an actual 0 into the array, if the user wants to, which is a good thing.)

Also, you totally don't need the `else { continue; }` part.

Also, when I compile your code, my compiler complains

```
warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'
note: change return type to 'int'
```

My compiler is correct.  `main()` must be declared as returning `int`; `void main()` is wrong.

But I want to say a few more words about setting up this kind of loop in the first place.  It can be surprisingly tricky to write a loop meeting the requirement "Allow the user to enter up to 5 numbers, or enter a `0` to indicate early termination".  We see all sorts of incredibly contorted programs attempting to do that.  Your loop was actually fine, and I want to congratulate you for that.  Let's look at why it was fine:

First, go back to the requirement: "Allow the user to enter up to 5 numbers, or enter a `0` to indicate early termination".  So it looks like were going to need a loop, but a mildly special loop, with *two* different termination conditions.  We're done entering numbers if the user has entered five numbers, **or** if the user enters a 0.  But simple loops (both `for` loops and `while` loops) have a single termination condition.  How shall we arrange for a second one?

One possibility is to write an ordinary `for` loop that runs from 0 to 5, with the first condition `i<5` in the `for` loop header, and then use a `break` statement to implement the second condition, breaking out of the loop early if the user enters `0`.  And of course that's the way you implemented it.  In fact it's probably the most straightforward way of implementing it.  In particular this is just the sort of thing the `break` statement is intended for: breaking out of a loop early if there's an exceptional condition.  But there are other possibilities, too.

In particular, in a real program, we'd probably want to let the user enter as many numbers as he wanted to.  So instead of size 5, we'd probably make the array with 100 cells, or 1,000, or some number bigger than the number of elements the user would ever enter.  And if we did that, it would end up being the *normal* case that the user typed "0" when he was done entering numbers.  Now, the exceptional condition would be that we actually got to the array limit without seeing a "0".  Also we might want to print a special message in that case, warning the user that we ran out of space for all his numbers.  How might we write a loop under those assumptions?

Here is my first attempt.  (It will look pretty strange at first, but I'll explain.)

```
#define ARRSIZE 100

int main()
{
    int i = 0, n, arr[ARRSIZE];

    printf("Input up to %d integers:\n", ARRSIZE);
    while(1) {
        if(i >= ARRSIZE) {
            printf("warning: too many numbers (max %d)\n", ARRSIZE);
            break;
        }
        printf("%d : ", i+1);
        if(scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) break;
        if(arr[i] == 0) break;

        i++;
    }

    n = i;

    printf("The %d integers stored in the array are:\n", n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Here I've written what looks like an infinite loop, `while(1)`.  Here I've placed both conditions inside the loop, as `break` statements.  This looks weird, I agree, but in some ways I prefer it: now both conditions are "in the same place", so to speak.  The first thing we do is make sure there's room for the next number to be entered, and if not, we print a warning message and break out of the loop.  Next we print the prompt.  Next we enter the number, and if its 0 (or nonnumeric or `EOF`), we break out of the loop.

This works, although there's one little oddity.  If the user enters (in this case) 100 numbers, what will happen next is that we'll print `warning: too many numbers (max 100)` and exit the loop.  But the user hadn't actually entered too many numbers *yet*.  We accuse him too early.  What if he was *planning* on entering exactly 100 numbers, then entering "0"?

Since the 0 value is a sentinel that isn't actually used in the array, we don't even need to store it in the array.  We can rearrange things a bit further, by introducing a new temporary variable `num` that we initially read the user's entered number into, before later moving it into `arr[i]` if it's not 0, and if there is room.  (To avoid confusion I'm also renaming `n` to `nnum`):

```
int i = 0, num, nnum, arr[ARRSIZE];

printf("Input your numbers, terminated by \"0\" or EOF:\n");
while(1) {
    printf("%d : ", i+1);
    if(scanf("%d", &num) != 1) break;
    if(num == 0) break;
    if(i >= ARRSIZE) {
        printf("warning: too many numbers (max %d)\n", ARRSIZE);
        break;
    }

    arr[i++] = num;
}

nnum = i;
```

I'm not saying this is the way you'd want to write the loop -- as I said, the simpler loop you wrote is fine.  And it may seem like I've made too bit a deal out of little issues like "now, the exceptional condition would be that we actually got to the array limit", or "we accuse the user too early".  But when you're writing a real program, often those "little issues" end up making a big difference, so they're worth thinking about.